# Crontab once a weekday at startup

Tags: cron

Is that possible to run task once a week at startup?
For example:
on monday after reboot starts command 1 
on tuesday after reboot starts command 2 (but does not starts command1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a single `cron` entry with `@reboot`, and use a script to select the command. For example, in `crontab`:

```
@reboot bash /path/to/my/script.sh
```

And in `/path/to/my/script.sh`:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

case $(date +%u) in
    1)
        echo Monday
        command 1
        ;;
    2)
        echo Tuesday
        command 2
        ;;
    #   ...
    7)
        echo Sunday
        ;;
esac
```